# Highlighting a specific word in a text document using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const boldText = () => {
    const text=document.getElementById('blog-text');
    const originalText = text.innerHTML;
    const input = document.getElementById('text-to-search');

    if (input.value) {
        const word=input.value.trim();
        const regexp = new RegExp(word,'gi');
        reactStringReplace(originalText,regexp, (match, i) => (
            <span key={i} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{match}</span>
        ));
    }
}
```

I tried to use this code in order to highlight a specific word given by the user in a document(input by user) and replace the word in the original document but I am not receiving any change on clicking the button in the document.

I also tried this code below but still was awarded with no changes in the document.

*Below that I have also provided the js snippet

```
const boldText = () => {
    let btext = document.getElementById('blog-text');
    console.log(document.getElementById('blog-text').value);

    let input = document.getElementById('text-to-search').value;
    console.log(document.getElementById('text-to-search').value);
    input = input.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,"\\$&");
    let pattern = new RegExp(`${input}`, "gi");

    reactStringReplace(btext,pattern, (match, i) => (
        <span key={i} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{match}</span>
    ));
}
```

This is the Complete JavaScript file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import "./Blog.css"
import reactStringReplace from 'react-string-replace';

export default function Blog() {
    // const boldText = () => {
    // const text=document.getElementById('blog-text');
    // const originalText=text.innerHTML
    // const input=document.getElementById('text-to-search');

    // if(input.value){
    //     const word=input.value.trim();
    //     const regexp=new RegExp(word,'gi');
    //     reactStringReplace(originalText,regexp, (match, i) => (
    //             <span key={i} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{match}</span>
    //         ));
    // }

    const boldText = () => {
        let btext = document.getElementById('blog-text');
        console.log(document.getElementById('blog-text').value);

        let input = document.getElementById('text-to-search').value;
        console.log(document.getElementById('text-to-search').value);
        input = input.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,"\\$&");
        let pattern = new RegExp(`${input}`, "gi");

        reactStringReplace(btext,pattern, (match, i) => (
            <span key={i} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{match}</span>
        ));
    }

    const handleOnChangetit = (event) => {
        setTitText(event.target.value);
    }
    const handleOnChangedes = (event) => {
        setDesText(event.target.value);
    }
    const [titleText, setTitText] = useState("Enter Title here....");
    const [desText, setDesText] = useState("Enter Text here....");

    return (
        <>
            <div className="blogButtons">
                <input className="searchbar" type="search" id="text-to-search" 
                  placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search..." />
                <button className="btn btn-outline-success" onClick={boldText} type="submit"><i 
                  className="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"> Bold Text</i></button>
            </div>
            <div className="textbox">
                <textarea type="text" value={titleText} onChange={handleOnChangetit} 
                  className='blogtitle' />
                <textarea type="text" id="blog-text" value={desText} onChange={handleOnChangedes} 
                  className='blogarea' />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of an anti-pattern to access the DOM directly in your react code.  Because of re-rendering and rebuilding the actual DOM on screen.  It is better to use hooks to build references to your JSX elements into your components for when you need to access or mutate the values.

I can't see the inputs or the blog text components, so I'll have to give you an out of context example:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "React"
import reactStringReplace from 'react-string-replace'

const MyComponent = ({ blogText }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

  const blogText = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchValue = inputValue.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
    let pattern = new RegExp(`${searchValue}`, "gi")
    reactStringReplace(blogText.current, pattern, (match, i) => (
      <span key={i} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{match}</span>
    ))
  }, [inputValue, blogText])

  return (
    <div>
     <input 
       value={inputValue}
       onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} 
       type="text"
       className="text-to-search"
     />
     <p className="blog-text" ref={blogText}>
      {blogText}
     </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

##### Explanation of Hooks

`useState`

- This is a hook that returns an array containing both a value and a function that sets the value
- These values are destructured from the array at use of the hook
- Assign the value to your input, and an `onChange` handler that updates the values when the user types

`useEffect`

- Calls a function whenever a render is triggered
- The render can be targeted to a specific change, in this case, the change of the input
- Put the targeted change in the Dependency Array, the second argument to useEffect

`useRef`

- Use this function to assign a value to a DOM element that will persist between renders.
- This value is "safe" from rerenders, and is safe to use inside a dependency array of `useEffect` for example.
- Use this instead of DOM methods
- Access the referenced value with `blogText.current`

Essentially, I am using `useEffect` to listen for changes to `inputValue`, which is using State to control the text input. When this state value changes, it runs a function that calls `reactStringReplace` with the reference to `blogText`.